# How can I wait until widget is built before pushing a route?

Tags: dart, flutter

New flutter dev here. In my testing I've noticed that pushing and popping embedded platform views can cause a Flutter app to drop frames. Is there a way that I can wait until a widget is built before I push the route?

For example, with the Google Maps Flutter widget, is there a way that I can instantiate it and built it asynchronously, and then only push the route to show it once it is loaded? I'm trying to create seamless experience for the user.

Any information is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Could you please add your code? If you want an answer to whether it is possible: yes, of course. However, it depends on what you are trying to do. You *cannot* build a widget before it is inserted into the build tree (obviously?). You *can* load all data, do all computation before pushing a route.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot I'm asking in general here. Sample code would just involve a button that pushes a Google Map view (within a scaffold). I can post some code if that would help.

Comment: @JacobPhillips gave a general answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the logic in an `async` function.

```
Future buildAndNavigate(BuildContext context) async {
  Widget widgey = await buildWidget();
  Navigator.push(context, ...);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, to be more clear and precise in my question: before a user navigates to a google map view, building it in the background so when a user pops the route to view the map, there's no loading or jittering.